# Detecting where a file is being loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm taking on a site build in WordPress and I did a few scans through it, one with SEMRush.

It this results in a mixed content issue with the culprit being a reference to http://www.29wp.org/jquery.js.

The issue is, when I view page source and inspect it, it's not there.

It's as if this is being loaded and removed somehow, but doing a grep results in nothing.

I checked the usual places for where this was loaded, and eventually checked the network tab in chrome inspector -- nothing there that looks like this file.

I did a scan on all the site files -- nothing shown.

I then did a search in the DB - still nothing.

Any others ways you can think of for finding where this is being loaded?

Thanks

Comment: too broad. if there is a mixed content issue, so there should be the source and iniator of loading that file. provide console error as it's in the browser console

Comment: Except that it doesn't show in the browser console, just through the external crawler (in my case, SEMRush)

Comment: then the problem is with the crawler, which may try to load some other files from iframe and etc. if your console is clean, then all is ok with content( mixed content not exists )

Answer (score 0):

Check if there are CURL requests in any of your Wordpress php files , If you found `curl_init()` or any other curl function that you don't know anything about , Then that might be the reason. 
Note "This is how latest web malwares work" .